# Global serial dispatch queue

Tags: cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

Still getting the GCD into my head and had an issue where I wanted a single serial queue to span the lifetime of my view controller.  Have several blocks I want to perform on the single queue in different parts of the class.

Two main reasons is that I want to avoid locks as I have been told that @synchronise is not best practice anymore and have several get requests to the internet I need to synchronise.

My solution is to create a serial queue, but its scope is only in the method where I define it. I don't want to use the global queue as its a concurrent queue and I specifically want a serial queue.

So I have solved it, I believe, by defining my queue as follows:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    dispatch_queue_t mySerialQueue;
}

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (!mySerialQueue) 
    mySerialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myAppQueue", NULL);
}

- (void)myMethod
{
    dispatch_async(mySerialQueue, ^{
    //My block code here
    });
}

- (void)myOtherMethod
{
    dispatch_async(mySerialQueue, ^{
    //My other block code here
    });
}

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    free(mySerialQueue);
}
```

Comment: Also, when I profile the test app, I get no memory leaks, but if I remove "free(mySerialQueue) I get a memory leak

Comment: Glad to hear you've solved it.

Comment: You should release the queue with `dispatch_release`, not `free`.  In addition, you need to call super in your implementations of `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: Also, I really don't see how this is any better than just using `dispatch_async` where you need it.

Comment: Hi, my question is, is it best practise to globally declare a serial queue in my h file and is it ok to use free() to release it?  Assume super is called in the necessary methods as I only included code relating to my issue.  So apologies for not being clearer.

Comment: After some more testing, this is NOT a solution.  App crashes with thie initial solution above.  What I want is a serial queue that I can dispatch blocks to from different parts of the object.  Still searching.......

Comment: My confusion also is the globally available Main dispatch queue.  I know I dont create the main dispatch queue but I still send tasks to it on viewWillDisapear, so what is the correct way to cleanup after I have finished with the main dispatch queue

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved the issue.  I misunderstood the concurrency programming guide where it said that the **dispatch_get_main_queue** would be run on the main thread.  This queue is the correct solution for my requirements and it more importantly allows serialisation of my blocks to be run on the FIFO order.  Thanks for your input guys as I am a bit of a novice still.